# PubSub Cloud Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, message-queue, publish-subscribe, aws-iot

I am looking for a PubSub or Message Queue cloud service with the following requirements:

1. Pay per message
2. The ability to subscribe on-demand with a client sdk
3. Support for topics

[Amazon MQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/) does **not** satisfy these requirements because it is not pay per message.

[Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) does **not** satisfy these requirements because it doesn't allow on-demand subscription using a client sdk.

[Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) does **not** satisfy these requirements because it doesn't support topics.

---

[AWS IoT Core](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/) does satisfy these requirements.

However, I'm curious if there are other options - possibly even outside the AWS ecosystem. I'm hesitant to use AWS IoT since I wouldn't be using it for an IoT use case.

Should I move forward with AWS IoT Core or are there other options I should be considering?

Comment: Why per message?  Is batching of costs (i.e. X messages for Y cost) not appropriate?  Are you, for example really going to account for USD $0.0000245 / message (from a service I've used that isn't AWS)?

Comment: Per message is important because at the beginning I'm going to have a very low volume. A low enough volume that a t2.micro doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you given Google Cloud pub/sub service a thought? https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/

Comment: I've used [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) for this before.  Not per message pricing but an intro tier for free of a million messages/month.

Comment: Questions of this nature are off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you need help using a tool, please post a specific question for that purpose.